# Unable to submit forms using PhantomJS Webdriver and Java

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, phantomjs

I'm in the middle of writing a program in java. One of the functions is to log in to a website with a username and password. I originally wrote this basic function to log in to a page using the ChromeDriver.

```
    public void Login() {
        System.out.println("Logging In");
        driver.get(url);
        ScreenShot("/Users/Adam/Documents/Screens/1.jpg");
        WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"username\"]"));
        login.sendKeys(username + Keys.TAB + password);
        ScreenShot("/Users/Adam/Documents/Screens/2.jpg");
    }
```

The function above works in Chromedriver, however when I run the same function in phantomjs the result isn't the same. Here's the error output.

`Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: {"errorMessage":"'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'c.name=this.name')","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, image/png","Connection":"Keep-Alive","Content-Length":"63","Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","Host":"localhost:48788"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"id\":\":wdc:1421947793877\",\"value\":[\"usernamepassword\"]}","url":"/value","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"value","directory":"/","path":"/value","relative":"/value","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/value","queryKey":{},"chunks":["value"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/4562eec0-a25c-11e4-a2af-d1362c6e21bf/element/%3Awdc%3A1421947793877/value"}}
Command duration or timeout: 811 milliseconds`

By looking at the error above, it looks like the information is being submitted to the form but some but the page is throwing an error.

I've also tried another approach, although it still doesn't work, it doesn't give me an error either...

```
    public void Login() {
        System.out.println("Logging In");
        driver.get(url);
        ScreenShot("/Users/Adam/Documents/Screens/1.jpg");
        WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"login\"]"));
        login.sendKeys(Keys.TAB + username + Keys.TAB + password + Keys.ENTER);
        ScreenShot("/Users/Adam/Documents/Screens/2.jpg");
    }
```

Instead of locating the username field, the function above finds the form itself and tried to enter the data. The result is the username and password being filled in but the form doesn't get submitted.

Any possible solutions or ideas on where to look for help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was pretty simple actually... After this driving me crazy for a few days I though, why not update Ghostdriver... So I did and now everything is working perfectly. Probably the first thing I should have tried, but hey ho...

The issue was with Phantomjs 1.9.7. Problem was fixed after updating to version 1.9.8.